# Same hashCode but two different entries in HashMap

Tags: java, hashmap, hashcode

What I know is: While inserting elements in the HashMap, Java checks value of hashCode and inserts that element in inside the HashMap and while retrieving the object from HashMap, Java checks the value of HashCode and retrieved the object that has the value generated from that HashCode. Is this correct?

I created a modal to override default implementation of HashCode. Every time that modal is called, it gives back a same value. So, if we add that modal again and again, why entries in HashMap are increasing?

Here is my code:

Modal:

```
 public class MyModal {
  int empId;
 String empName;

@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) return true;
    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

    MyModal myModal = (MyModal) o;

    if (empId != myModal.empId) return false;
    if (empName != null ? !empName.equals(myModal.empName) : myModal.empName != null) return false;

    return true;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return 1;
}

public MyModal(int empId, String empName) {
    this.empId = empId;
    this.empName = empName;
}
}
```

---

```
public class TestHashCode {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    HashMap<MyModal, Integer> hashMap = new HashMap<>();

    MyModal modal1 = new MyModal(1, "a");
    MyModal modal2 = new MyModal(2, "b");

    hashMap.put(modal1, 1);
    hashMap.put(modal2, 2);

    System.out.println("Size is" + hashMap.size());
    System.out.println(modal1.hashCode() + " "+modal2.hashCode());
}
}
```

---

Output:

```
Size is2
1 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hash collisions aren't the only limiting factor in the map construction, however returning a constant `1` is a "worst" case Map and it behaves like a LinkedList (every element is in one bucket). From the [`Object.hashCode()` Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode%28%29)

> It is *not required* that if two objects are unequal according to the `equals(java.lang.Object)` method, then calling the hashCode method on each of the two objects must produce distinct integer results. However, the programmer should be aware that producing distinct integer results for unequal objects may improve the performance of hash tables.

Answer (score -1):

Both HashCode and Equals need to be implemented. Hash code is used to narrow the search in equals need to be implemented to define equality. Two unequal objects can have same hashcode but does not mean they are equal.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode().